# Is there a workaround for QLabel::setOpenExternalLinks to use inside a SNAP installation?

Tags: qt, snapcraft

I am using a QLabel as a hyperlink in my QT-application on Linux.

```
QLabel *link = new QLabel();
link->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
link->setText("<a href='http://www.company.com'>Company</a>");
```

Everything works fine except when I install the app via SNAPCRAFT I get the following error while cklicking the label.

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.SafeLauncher was not provided by any .service files
```

Is there already a workaround for that problem or do I need to specify a plugin in my snapcraft.yaml?

```
apps:
  animationmaker:
    command: desktop-launch AnimationMaker
    plugs: [x11,home,unity7]
```

Edit:

I already tried out to use snapd-xdg-open as mentioned [here](http://www.ktechpit.com/linux/using-xdg-open-snap-package-open-external-url/) but get the same error.

```
parts:  
  snapd-xdg-open:
    source: https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapd-xdg-open.git
    plugin: copy
    files:
      data/xdg-open: bin/xdg-open
    stage-packages:
      - dbus
```